# Infinite loop on left outer join

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, join

I have a problem with PostgreSQL 9.6.5.

I want to select users from one table who are not in another table. My request is logical and "works" in some cases and not in others.

Let me explain it to you,  I made this request:

```
          SELECT count(*)
            FROM api.user_accounts AS aua
 LEFT OUTER JOIN teams.user_accounts AS tua ON aua.id = tua.api_user_account_id
      INNER JOIN public.user_accounts AS pua ON aua.user_account_id = pua.id
           WHERE tua.id IS NULL 
             AND pua.creation_date > '2018-03-01' AND pua.creation_date < '2018-04-01'
```

This request doesn't work (infinite loop or very long request ?), so I ran an `EXPLAIN SELECT...` and I got this :

```
Aggregate  (cost=7743.42..7743.43 rows=1 width=8)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=394.68..7743.42 rows=1 width=0)
        Join Filter: (aua.user_account_id = pua.id)
        ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=394.68..2175.00 rows=1 width=4)
              Hash Cond: (aua.id = tua.api_user_account_id)
              Filter: (tua.id IS NULL)
              ->  Seq Scan on user_accounts aua  (cost=0.00..1396.55 rows=72155 width=8)
              ->  Hash  (cost=253.19..253.19 rows=11319 width=8)
                    ->  Seq Scan on user_accounts tua  (cost=0.00..253.19 rows=11319 width=8)
        ->  Seq Scan on user_accounts pua  (cost=0.00..5460.89 rows=8603 width=4)
              Filter: ((creation_date > '2018-03-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone) AND (creation_date < '2018-04-01 00:00:00+02'::timestamp with time zone))
```

Now, get ready, I restart this request by changing the date, instead of getting all the dates below `'2018-04-01'`, I get those below `'2018-04-02'`. and that WORKS !!

Request for the second try:

```
          SELECT count(*)
            FROM api.user_accounts AS aua
 LEFT OUTER JOIN teams.user_accounts AS tua ON aua.id = tua.api_user_account_id
      INNER JOIN public.user_accounts AS pua ON aua.user_account_id = pua.id
           WHERE tua.id IS NULL 
             AND pua.creation_date > '2018-03-01' AND pua.creation_date < '2018-04-02'
    ----------------------------------------------change here-----------------^
```

Explain for the second try:

```
Aggregate  (cost=7669.27..7669.28 rows=1 width=8)
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=2175.01..7669.26 rows=1 width=0)
        Hash Cond: (pua.id = aua.user_account_id)
        ->  Seq Scan on user_accounts pua  (cost=0.00..5460.89 rows=8895 width=4)
              Filter: ((creation_date > '2018-03-01 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone) AND (creation_date < '2018-04-02 00:00:00+02'::timestamp with time zone))
        ->  Hash  (cost=2175.00..2175.00 rows=1 width=4)
              ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=394.68..2175.00 rows=1 width=4)
                    Hash Cond: (aua.id = tua.api_user_account_id)
                    Filter: (tua.id IS NULL)
                    ->  Seq Scan on user_accounts aua  (cost=0.00..1396.55 rows=72155 width=8)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=253.19..253.19 rows=11319 width=8)
                          ->  Seq Scan on user_accounts tua  (cost=0.00..253.19 rows=11319 width=8)
```

EDIT:

- When I change the where clause to `tua.id IS NOT NULL`, that works, but I have the opposite result to the one expected.
- I've tried it on other computers, and all the requests work. The problem seems local. (I already checked if the versions were different)

EDIT 2:
I have found a solution, but it is not beautyful to see ...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
    (SELECT aua.* FROM api.user_accounts AS aua
    INNER JOIN public.user_accounts AS pua ON aua.user_account_id = pua.id
    WHERE pua.creation_date > '2018-03-01' AND pua.creation_date < '2018-04-01'
    LIMIT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM api.user_accounts)
    ) AS aua
LEFT OUTER JOIN teams.user_accounts AS tua ON aua.id = tua.api_user_account_id
WHERE tua.id IS NULL
```

So, why is the PostgreSQL explanation so different on the 2 queries? why the second one works and not the first one? I don't understand what's going on.

Comment: Unrelated, but: the inner join between tua and pua turns the outer join between aua and tua into an inner join

Comment: With combination of `OUTER JOIN` and filtering `NULL`s you are creating some kind of "broken" NOT EXISTS. Why not use `NOT EXISTS` directly?

Comment: @Ingaz ; Thanks for your reply, it seems to work !